# how to know which button is clicked " first""

Tags: android, database, events

I have an activity that contains 9 button's that gives some value. I wanna get that value in clicked order - how is it possible? Here is my code:

```
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            s1="1";
            i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.lockk1);
            i1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
           // i1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
            return false;
        }
    });       
});


Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.butt);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("**********"+s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6+s7+s8+s9+"******");
          mydb=LockerActivity.this.openOrCreateDatabase("pattern", MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
            Cursor cr= mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM patterntable", null);
 if (cr.getCount() > 0) {                   
    if(cr.moveToFirst()){
            do 
            {
            pass = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("password"));

            password=s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6+s7+s8+s9;
            if(password.equals(pass))
            {   
                Intent i=new Intent(LockerActivity.this,first.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
                 Intent i=new Intent(LockerActivity.this,LockerActivity.class);
                 startActivity(i);
                 }        
                }   while (cr.moveToNext());

             cr.close();
             mydb.close();
    }   
    }
 } 
});
```

Comment: simply use int id=arg0.getId(); and then use switch statement

Comment: thanks for ur help but it doesnot gives which button clicked ""first"" it only gives which is clicked

Comment: Add a simple log.v("clicked","1/2/3/4/5----") in every instance of your onClick for every button, it'll show you in the log the instance of the button that was clicked

Comment: we can settag for each button then using a boolean variable we can set First click to ture  and get buton tag in onClick function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void updateDisplay(View v){
    s1=(String) ((Button)v).getTag();
    ss.add(s1);
    System.out.println("nos are**********"+ss);
}
```

set some tag to the corresponding buttons

Answer (score 0):

I'm not Android programmer but If I'd need to do same on iOS I'd do the following:

```
int firstPressedButton = -1;
void settingFirstPressedButton (int buttonPressed)
{
if (firstPressedButton == -1)   //when firstPressedButton = -1 it means no button was pressed
  firstPressedButton = buttonPressed;
}
```